# Remove Faces Permanently from Photos Library

Tags: photos, photos.app

Is there a way to permanently remove a name from the faces in the new Photos app?

Example:
When you tag a face accidentally with "John" instead of "John Miller", you can delete the face associated with "John" and remove the "John" tag from all your photos, but "John" will still be suggested every time you tag a face and start with "J...".

I guess this is especially annoying when you type fast and tag a lot of faces, where you will end up with dozens of typo/etc. names that will be suggested to you every time you enter a name...

Comment: Just rename the incorrect tag. Once no references to it exist, it will no longer be offered as a suggestion.

Comment: I already deleted the incorrect tag, but it will still show up in the dropdown menu that appears when tagging a face?

Comment: only if one variant is a 'face' but the other is a Contact - or should be… I did a lot of juggling with Faces in the transition to Photos & the added Contacts tagging, & that's how it was working for me

Comment: Ah okay, so all the other faces are 'contacts' in my case, any suggestions then?

Comment: I never figured out how to get rid of the Contacts, sorry. I do prefer to have my Faces named 'Fliss F' rather than felicity.fotheringto-smythe@longcompany.com ... It just seems... more friendly;)

Comment: Oh, by other faces I meant the ones that were correctly tagged (people whom I all have as contacts). The "not-contact" tags are the wrong ones...

Comment: iirc, the way I got rid of the typos & confusions [other than Contacts] was, rather than removing the faces from that tag, I renamed the 'bad' tag to the 'good' name. It's been a while since I did it & it was very much trial & error.

Comment: Okay, so I tried different things and none of them seem to work: 1) Tag a photo with the "bad tag" and delete the tag/face from the Faces page. 2) Rename the photos tagged with the "bad tag". 3) Delete the tag from the photos that have a "bad tag". - While the bad tag will disappear from the Faces page, it will still appear in the dropdown menu when you tag a new face. At this point, I'm pretty sure there is no way around this right now. Since no new contacts are created, this information is probably stored in the *.photoslibrary file and I'm not sure if it can be edited directly...

Answer (score 1):

The iOS 12 and macOS 10.14 versions of Photos makes this significantly easier.

Select the face / person / name in question and then select:

- Remove this person (from macOS)
- Remove (from iOS)

That purges the name and face from ones it will select in the People Album. I do see that both platforms will find names from your contacts, so if you just removed "Mary" from your album and you have any contacts with Mary in them, you will still get prompted. Temporarily deleting the contacts (make a backup) or deleting the sync of cloud contacts like iCloud and Outlook.com (or the many other contact sync options) you can test that Photos doesn't have that name anymore to suggest to you.